# Is there a Permission, where you can restore Database, without being the db_owner?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question is in the title. :)

Comment: Where the backup you're restoring from could presumably be one in which you *are* db_owner, negating any benefit from this separate permission? No, I don't think there is.

Comment: no, you have to tell the DB owner, that you've destroyed the data^^

Answer (score 0):

From the [RESTORE DATABASE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> **Permissions**
>
> If the database being restored does not exist, the user
>   must have CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE.
>   If the database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the
>   database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always
>   exists).
>
> RESTORE permissions are given to roles in which membership
>   information is always readily available to the server. Because fixed
>   database role membership can be checked only when the database is
>   accessible and undamaged, which is not always the case when RESTORE is
>   executed, members of the db_owner fixed database role do not have
>   RESTORE permissions.